# Drawing SVG Image on SurfaceView using menu items

Tags: android, imageview, surfaceview, ondraw, android-optionsmenu

I want to draw several SVG images using `SurfaceView`, and each image needs to be drawn when clicking the specific menu item. Every option in the menu has an `id` and when performing click on one, I want the image with that `id` to be drawn.

Using different sugestions I found, I created a `View` that extends `SurfaceView` as below:

```
public class DrawObject extends SurfaceView {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    public DrawObject(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawObject(Context context, ImageView imageView) {
        super(context);
        this.imageView = imageView;

        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                draw(canvas);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
        });

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),imageView.getId());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(imageView!=null) {
            Drawable drawable1 = imageView.getDrawable();
            drawable1.setBounds(100, 100, 0, 0);
            drawable1.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

For my activity (`DesignSceneSW`), where I have the `OptionsMenu` defined, I created the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DesignSceneSW">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/barColor"
        app:title="@string/create_your_design"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_design"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/textBarColor"
        />
    <com.stud.scriptreality.classes.DrawObject
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewID"
        android:background="@color/textBarColor"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in the `Java` file I get the view using `DrawObject drawView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewID);`.

My problem is that I'm not sure how am I supposed to draw when clicking an item from the menu, as I don't need to set the content as `setContentView(drawView)`, because I need to draw several images on the same surface.

I tried creating another `DrawObject` like:

```
 public void drawImage(ImageView imv, Canvas canvas) {
    DrawObject dobj = new DrawObject(getApplicationContext(),imv); //the imageView to be drawn
    dobj.draw(canvas);
 }
```

in a method that I call for every click on the menu. I've read that I don't need to create another `DrawObject`, but only calling `drawView.draw(canvas)` doesn't help me.

What am I doing wrong?
Any suggestion is highly appreciated!